# Slack interactive request doesn't hit designated ASP.NET controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm developing SaaS application which will be integrated witch Slack using it's interactive messaging feature. Right now I managed to make everything work on my local machine (using ngrok) - when I hit button in Slack it makes `HTTP POST` request to URL I've set up in configuration and I'm able to handle it and send response. So far so good.

In my production environment however I use nginx as a reverse proxy server and my application runs behind it inside Docker container. For some reason on this environment controller action that is supposed to handle Slack incoming requests is not invoked at all. If I make the same request by hand (using Insomnia) correct action inside controller is invoked. I suspect it may have something to do with

[Per Slack documentation](https://api.slack.com/interactivity/handling#payloads)

> The body of that request will contain a payload parameter. Your app should parse this payload parameter as JSON.

Knowing that I made an action

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Interactive(string payload)
```

Nothing fancy in routing configuration

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

In my logs it looks like this

Manual request:

```
wget --quiet \
--method POST \
--header 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--body-data 'payload=[correct json as in Slack documentation]' \
--output-document \
- https://application.com/slack/interactive
```

Results with

```
Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://application.com/slack/interactive application/x-www-form-urlencoded 2095
Executing endpoint 'Application.Controllers.SlackController.Interactive (Application)'
Route matched with {action = "Interactive", controller = "Slack"}. Executing controller action with signature System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult] Interactive(System.String) on controller Application.Controllers.SlackController (Application).
Request finished in 127.2643ms 302
```

Request made by Slack itself

```
Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://application.com/slack/interactive application/x-www-form-urlencoded 3029
Request finished in 108.7831ms 302
```

Logs indicating appropriate action being invoked are missing.

Because it works flawlessly on my localhost I suspect it has to be related with this reverse-proxy component (it seems more probable than it being caused by running inside Docker container, but who knows?)

Ngnix is configured as follows

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    # listen 80;
    # listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /var/ssl/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/ssl/privkey.pem;
    client_max_body_size 100M;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security    "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
    add_header X-Frame-Options              SAMEORIGIN;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options       nosniff;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection             "1; mode=block";

    resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=5s;
    set $upstream http://application;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         $upstream;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_ssl_certificate /var/ssl/fullchain.pem;
        proxy_ssl_certificate_key /var/ssl/privkey.pem;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

I've tried changing method signature, but without any success. I'm not experienced enough with nginx and it acting as reverse proxy to be able to figure any configuration-related issues by myself. I would really love any ideas on what this strange behavior may be related to.

Comment: Have you tried viewing the nginx logs? You should be able to access these on the nginx pod. This should include all incoming requests and also include details about how it's tried to resolve the requests.

Comment: Yeah, sure! I did inspect them, but unfortunately it did not reveal any obvious errors. What I've tried is creating API controller and using it as handler for Slack requests (previously it was "ordinary" controller). After that change and using `[Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]` alongside with `[FromForm] string payload` I was finally able to process Slack requests